# Design pattern for returning responses from child threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am looking for a design pattern where the parent thread will spawn multiple child threads. Each child thread will perform some computation and return an appropriate result.

The parent thread will be waiting for the child threads to complete. After all child threads are completed, the consolidated result will be sent to the parent thread.

The parent thread will then proceed with consolidated result.

Comment: Why are you not using `future`? `cyclic barrier` is intended for use  as **repeatable** waiting of one or more threads. For wait **one-short** thread(s) `join` is sufficient.

Comment: Sounds like [ForkJoinTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) or, if you insist on doing it manually, a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) will work.

Comment: Focused the title and question to help clarify the problem, dropped an inappropriate tag and improved the grammar.

Comment: Will the parent thread be **consolidating the results**, or is there some other process that is doing this piece of work?

Comment: Hi Brett Walker  yes parent thread will be consolidating results and perform some actions on basis of result obtained from child threads

Answer (score 0):

Check the `join` method of `Thread` class. Here is a working sample:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Threads {

 public void callChildren() throws Exception {

   Thread t = new Thread(new ChildThread());
   t.start();
   t.join();
   System.out.print(t.getName());
   System.out.println(", status = " + t.isAlive());
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++) {
            new Threads().callChildren();
         }

         System.out.println("Printing from Parent thread after all child thread are complete.");
   }


  private class ChildThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started:::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread ended:::"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: This approach will not walk every thread spawnned will be running a task which will result some value. So Callable will be required and future will be used to track the result returned by task

Answer (score 0):

Some existing answers recommend spawning threads manually -- I would not do that, but rather use an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead.

If you are allowed to use a 3rd party library, [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) will do the trick: Submitting your child tasks to a `ListeningExecutorService` will give you back a `ListenableFuture<T>` (with `T` being your result type). You can then e.g. use [`Futures.allAsList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList-java.lang.Iterable-) to combine all child task futures into one future (encapsulating the list of result values). If you then wait on this one future (with [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--)), you effectively wait on all child tasks. Once it completes, you can consolidate all result values and continue with your parent logic.

Here's a very minimal example:

```
public class Example {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CHILD_TASKS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        ListeningExecutorService listeningExecutorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executorService);

        List<ListenableFuture<String>> childTaskFutures = IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_CHILD_TASKS).mapToObj(
                taskIndex -> listeningExecutorService.submit(new ChildTask(taskIndex))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        ListenableFuture<List<String>> parentFuture = Futures.allAsList(childTaskFutures);
        try {
            List<String> results = parentFuture.get();
            results.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // proper handling...
        }
    }

    private static final class ChildTask implements Callable<String> {

        private final String taskName;

        private ChildTask(int taskIndex) {
            this.taskName = "Task " + taskIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(taskName + " executing...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return "Result of " + taskName;
        }
    }

}
```

If you can't use a 3rd party library, you can use a "traditional" [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to spawn the child tasks and use an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to process the resulting futures. The linked javadocs give examples for both aspects of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Threads cannot return a result. Child threads can communicate with the creating thread when the creator passes a reference to itself ("this") to the created threads, such as:

```
MyThread thd1 = new MyThread(this, latch);
```

The latch is a reference to a CountDownLatch. The creator also has a method that the created thread will call when it completes, such as:

```
public void saveResult1 (Object something) {

  object1 = something;
  latch.countDown();

}
```

The creator simply waits for all threads to finish with an await.

```
try {
    latch.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
```

When each created thread finishes its work it can call method saveResult... on the creator thread that saves the result somewhere and does a count down.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Can it be replaced by future a every child thread will be asynchronous task waiting for response from third party so it has to wait fro some time. How to handle that behavior in this ?

Comment: You don't actually have to wait. You can check latch.getCount() to determine how many threads have not responded. Until zero, do other work.

Comment: Thanks edharned.  well i have one doubt all child threads will be calling saveResult method for storing their method. How to avoind deadlock. By using synchronized / Cncurrent data structures will that be sufficient or something else needs to be employed .  Please suggest

Comment: Without knowing everything, making a design decision is unwise. However, in saveResult method I usually use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue as the thread save repository. Multiple threads may add to the Queue and multiple threads may poll the Queue. Using synchronized methods always has the potential for deadlock.